# Grails one-to-many select id very slow

Tags: hibernate, grails, one-to-many

I'm experiencing some very slow performance in some part of my application.
Let's say i have the following classes.

```
class Instrument{
 BigDecimal Value;
 String name;    
 InstrumentType type;
 InstrumentSubType sType;
 Country cls;
 Region reg;
 Sector sec;     
 static hasMany = [belongings: belongs] 
}

class DailyValuation{
   Instrument ins;
   Date valData;
   BigDecimal actualValue;
}
```

If i want to insert a new DailyValuation first i need to get the Instrument.
So after measuring time i got: the Instrument select takes ONE second with only
500 rows, and the insert takes 30 ms.

If i do a regular query on Mysql the select takes less than 10 ms. I know that Hibernate has some lazy and eager fetching features, so:

Is there a way to just select what i need? In my case i would only need the Instrument id.
I've tried the following:

```
def nin = Instrument.executeQuery("select a.id from Instrument a where name='BONUS1'")
DailyValuation dVal = new DailyValuation(ins:nin);
```

And after watching the Hibernate Log SQL i have one select which gets the id, and another one which gets the whole Instrument info.

How should i proceed in order to get this as fast as posible?

Thanks alot for your help.

Comment: Can you paste those hibernate queries ? "one select which gets the id, and another one which gets the whole Instrument info."

Answer (score 1):

The default GORM mappings using collections will be slow, and more so as the collection sizes increase. The typical pattern of adding a new `DailyValuation` is to use the dynamic `addToBelongings` method that's generated based on the key in the `hasMany` map for that domain class. By default that collection is lazy-loaded, so if it wasn't already initialized it will now be fully populated, then the new instance will be added (and its back-reference to the parent set if the mapping is bidirectional), and when you save the parent, Hibernate will notice that there's a new instance and save it. But that was a very wasteful approach, loading all 500 instances for nothing.

Technically it's not for nothing - the collection is a `Set` by default, so Hibernate needs to load all of the other instances to ensure that the new instance is unique. And if you configure it to be a `List`, Hibernate needs all of the other instances to make sure it's in the correct position, even if you're just adding it to the end.

A more direct and performant approach is to not use collections, but instead just set the parent instance in the child before saving. Remove the `hasMany` property from the `Instrument` class, and when you create new `DailyValuation` instances, just set the `Instrument` yourself, e.g.

```
Instrument parent = ...
def dailyValuation = new DailyValuation(params)
dailyValuation.ins = parent
if (dailyValuation.save()) {
   ...
}
else {
   ...
}
```

I did a [talk on this topic](http://www.infoq.com/presentations/GORM-Performance) a few years ago that's still relevant.